# mkdir -p ./build/brazil-documentation does not create directory and mkdir ./build/brazil-documentation says directory exists

Tags: mkdir

I am running into a problem here while writing a script.
When I run the below:

```
mkdir -p ./build/brazil-documentation
```

The directory does not get created. However, when I run the below:

```
mkdir ./build/brazil-documentation
```

I get an error saying the directory already exists.

What am I doing wrong here?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al ./build/` ?

Comment: Its empty..but i think i figured why. We had a post-release script running that was cleaning out everything under the build folder.

Comment: Oh! Nice you figured it out. `clean` should be ran before `build` to keep all artifacts and run an extra `release` or `publish` step that picks the artifacts you want from the build folder.

Comment: Yup! I updated our code so the `build` folder is not cleaned up after `release`. Thanks for your help!